# write a recursive function clean list(l1, l2) that takes two lists as input and returns a list of elements from l1 that are not present in l2

Tags: python-3.x

```
def clean_list(l1, l2):
    if l1 == l2:
        return 0
    if l1 == []:
        return clean_list
    if l1[0] not in l2:
        return l1[0] + clean_list(l1[1:], l2)
    else:
        return clean_list(l1[1:], l2)
unique = clean_list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [2,4,6])
print(unique)
```

Keep getting an error saying unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code:

1. In the base cases you return an int and a function, i.e. `return 0` and `return clean_list`.
2. In the third case you need to concatenate lists, you are concatenating and integer and a list `l1[0] + clean_list(l1[1:], l2)`.
3. If `l1` is empty (`not l1`) you should return the empty list.

That being said, you here is the code:

```
def clean_list(l1, l2):
    if l1 == l2:
        return []

    if not l1:
        return []

    if l1[0] not in l2:
        return [l1[0]] + clean_list(l1[1:], l2)
    else:
        return clean_list(l1[1:], l2)


unique = clean_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 6])
print(unique)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```